# How edit a file in php?

Tags: php

I can not edit a file in my system, the file doesn't go to the directory and does not change in the bank.

Basically I want to put this new file in the directory and replace it in the database.

> I tried to use this code that I only edit multiple files, but it
>   doesn't work with only 1 file ...

**My code:**

```
<?php  include('home.php'); include('con.php');

         $ID_contas = $_POST['ID_contas'];
         $tipo_pg = $_POST['tipo_pg'];
         $a1 = "";

         //Edit upload "comprovante"

         $name = $_FILES['comprovante']['name'];
         $tmp_name = $_FILES['comprovante']['tmp_name'];

         if(isset($name) && !empty($name)){
         $location = "uploads_pagamentos/";


         $extensao = strrchr($name, '.');

         $extensao = strtolower($extensao);

         $nome_arquivo = explode('.', $name)[0];

         $nome_final = '' . $nome_arquivo . '_comprovante_' . md5(microtime()) . $extensao;

         $a1 = ", comprovante = '$nome_final'";

         if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$nome_final)){
         $smsg = "Upload realizado com sucesso!!";
         }else{
         $fmsg = "Falha no Upload";
         }
         }else{
         $fmsg = "Selecione um arquivo";
         }

           $arquivos = "".$a1."";
 ?>
```

**Update:**

```
 $sqlupdate = "UPDATE contas SET ID_contas = '$ID_contas', tipo_pg = '$tipo_pg' ".$arquivos."
 WHERE ID_contas = '$ID_contas'";

 mysqli_query($link, $sqlupdate) or die ("Não foi possivel editar as
 informações no banco");

 $resultado = "Edição realizada com sucesso!!!";
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1011527)

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct, I forgot of to mention in form the **`enctype="multipart/form-data"`** :

```
<form action="edit_acc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```